# Why does Vista report that my Windows account not being in Administrators Role?

Tags: .net, powershell, windows-vista, user-accounts, windows-principal

Under Windows Vista, when I check whether my current user account is in **Administrators** role, I am getting a negative, as shown in the following picture.

Can anyone tell me why I am not in the Administrators role?  When I do the check if I am in "Debugger Users" role, I am getting "True"

[image: Not In Administrators Role]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Windows Vista, your account doesn't have the Administrator role unless you've elevated to that level through User Account Control.

My understanding is that you effectively have **two** user accounts -- one normal level, one administrator level -- with UAC mediating the switch between the two.

Comment: Technically you have only one account. You initially get a restricted token, when you elevate, you get an elevated token.

Comment: I found out how to check whether user is in Admins role or not through a link in another StackOverflow post - http://tinyurl.com/ct5t2b which links to http://tinyurl.com/m5ukz